# doctrine deleting has to be done twice

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, concrete5

I have the following DB structure and relations:

**Posts** -> OneToMany,cascade={"persist"} -> **Replies** -> OneToMany,cascade={"persist"} -> **Files entities** + **files on disk** -> **event** to delete files entities

**Posts** -> OneToMany,cascade={"persist"} -> **Files entities** + **files on disk** -> **event** to delete files entities

The thing about files is:

- deleting files entity (from application) deletes file on disk
- deleting file on disk (from file manager) fires an event deleting files entity

What I need is if a post is deleted, it cascades all the way to deleting replies, file entities and its files on disk. The chain of events is:

1. page controller:

```
post->remove();
```

2. Post class:

```
remove()
{
    PostFile::deleteFiles($this);
    Reply::deleteFiles($this);
    $em->remove($this);
    $em->flush();
}
```

3. PostFile:

```
deleteFiles($post)
{
    $files = $post->getFiles()->toArray();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $f->delete();
    }
}
```

4. Reply:

```
deleteFiles($post)
{
    $replies = $post->getReplies()->toArray();
    foreach ($replies as $reply) {
        if ($reply) {
            ReplyFile::deleteFiles($reply);
        }
    }
}
```

5. ReplyFile:

```
deleteFiles($reply)
{
    $files = $reply->getFiles()->toArray();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $f->delete();
    }
}
```

6. File deletion event:

```
Events::addListener('on_file_delete', function($event) {
    $f = $event->getFileObject();
    $fid = $file->getFileID();
    $fpf = PostFile::getByFileID($fid);
    $fpf->delete();
    $fpmf = ReplyFile::getByFileID($fid);
    $fpmf->delete();
});
```

Everything down the chain works fine, e.g. everything gets deleted, except for the post itself which doesn't get deleted, it has to be deleted twice. Why can that be?

Comment: Don't you need to persist between (s. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities)? I think without persisting you only remove it from the `Unit of Work`.

Comment: I've changed OneToMany,cascade={"persist"} to OneToMany,cascade={"remove"} and it seems to be working correctly now

Comment: Make an answer and accept it. Would be helpful for later visitors (if it's correct) ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing OneToMany,cascade={"persist"} to OneToMany,cascade={"remove"} seemed to have fixed it, now everything gets deleted on first try